# Creating a new Child Business Unit(BU) in order to given access to shared DE for Email Developer

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-template, content-builder, sfmc-business-unit

We have a single Business Unit (BU) for our organisation.
We are working with some external agency who design email templates for us.
We want to give them access only to 4 Data Extension and not other DE as we don't want to expose our data.

I planning to create a new BU for this purpose and then share only these 4 DE with the child BU.

My question is,

1. Is this okay/good practice to create a separate BU for this use case? Does this affect any of the data in the Parent BU?
2. Also will the user be able to access all our current content within Email Studio in the new Child BU?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a new business unit only for the agency as the business unit has a cost difficult to justify purely for email creation.
The agency does not require access to data extension unless there is a need for them to create and test personalisation with ampscript.

If the simply need to create the assets and preview, the preview will load without selecting a subscriber and can be sent to their inbox, all you need to do is to give them a content creator role and restrict access to other areas.

If there is a need to test personalisation then access to data extension is required and you can achieve it by sharing the 4 DE with the child BU.
The child BU will not have any impact in the master BU.
Regarding content builder, you will need to decide how to share/deploy content, so they could share from the sub-bu to the master BU.
Note that landing pages cannot be shared and will have to be manually recreated in the other BU.
The same applies to inbox messages.